# How would I open a file in shell if I don't have access to it?

Tags: c, linux, shell

So there is a text file, eg file.txt. In the same directory there are 2 other files that have code. One of the files has a code that if you satisfy it's if/else question then it will force open the file for you. My question is how would I change the value in the if/else question so that it force opens the file.
userd5c84@shell:/problems/aplit$ ls
aplit  aplit.c  flag.txt  Makefile
the code below is in the aplit.c and i'm trying to get into flag.txt

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                                                    
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                                                   
#include <fcntl.h>                                                                                                                                                    

int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                                                     
        int score = 0;                                                                                                                                                
        printf("CollageBored (R) Advanced Placement Literature Grader\n");                                                                                            
        if (argc != 2) {                                                                                                                                              
                printf("Usage: %s [essay]\n", argv[0]);                                                                                                               
                return 1;                                                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                                                             
        char buf[700];                                                                                                                                                
        strcpy(buf, argv[1]);                                                                                                                                         
        printf("-------------- YOUR SUBMISSION --------------\n");                                                                                                    
        printf("%s\n", buf);                                                                                                                                          
        printf("---------------------------------------------\n");                                                                                                    
        printf("According to our analysis, your response received a grade of %d!\n", score);                                                                          
        if (score > 12) {                                                                                                                                             
                uid_t uid = geteuid();                                                                                                                                
                setresuid(uid, uid, uid);                                                                                                                             
                FILE *fp;                                                                                                                                             
                fp = fopen("flag.txt", "r");                                                                                                                          
                char flag[64];                                                                                                                                        
                fgets(flag, 64, (FILE*) fp);                                                                                                                          
                printf("Wow, you're an HONOR student! Here's a flag: %s\n", flag);                                                                                    
        } else {                                                                                                                                                      
                printf("Sorry, you can only view the FLAG if you received a score greater than 12.\n");                                                               
                printf("\n");                                                                                                                                         
                printf("If you didn't do as well as you wanted, be sure to take a look at our rubric\n");                                                             
                printf("to see how we grade your essay!\n");                                                                                                          
                printf("********* RUBRIC ************ \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 0 - your essay sucks      * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 1 - impossible to achieve * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 2 - impossible to achieve * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 3 - impossible to achieve * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 4 - impossible to achieve * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 5 - impossible to achieve * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 6 - impossible to achieve * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 7 - impossible to achieve * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 8 - impossible to achieve * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("* 9 - impossible to achieve * \n");                                                                                                           
                printf("***************************** \n");                                                                                                           
        }                                                                                                                                                             
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is "force opening" of a file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know much about coding but i'm pretty sure it will open the flag.txt file if I somehow make it so the score > 12

Comment: Yes, but that does not change the fact if you can open the flag file or not. Either you do have permission on file system level or you don't. The condition cannot somehow magically change that. Apart from that this looks like `c` code to me. You certainly could change that, but that is not something that can simply be executed. It would have to be compiled and linked before, so you would need a full development environment. And for what? Do change a conditional? Why not simply leave that code away and open the file?

Comment: I can't open the file because it's denied to me

Comment: If you try another program and you still can't open it (a.k.a. "permission denied") then any C program you write won't help you. You need to ask the administrator to change permissions of the file so you can access it.

Comment: Yep, exatly. What does "it's denied to me" mean anyway? _How_ did you try to open it?

Comment: I tried to open it using cat and more

Comment: In the directory, run `ls -l` and show us the results.

Comment: -rwsr-xr-x 1 aplit aplit 7601 Nov  5 00:16 aplit
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  1574 Nov  4 23:52 aplit.c                               
-r--r----- 1 aplit aplit   29 Nov  4 23:52 flag.txt                              
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root    69 Nov  4 23:52 Makefile

Comment: The `s` in their means that the executable `aplit` runs with root permissions,  That is why it can open any file.  The file `flag.txt` can be opened by user `aplit` or anyone belonging to the group `aplit`.  If you want to open `flag.txt`, you need to ask someone to add you to that group.

Comment: This isn't a work related problem, it's just an assignment at school we have and they give us a problem that we have to solve. The answer to it is inside flag.txt. So I can't just ask because that would defeat the purpose of  learning how.

Comment: I can open aplit but it's just a jumble of nonsense, would you guys like to see it? By the way I really appreciate all of your help, you guys are the best.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to do a "stack exploit" to overwrite `score` to become 12 or more. That means entering a string of at least 704 characters as `argv[1]` on the command line so the `strcpy` will overwrite score.

This assumes an architecture/compiler that uses a stack and places the variables in the order as delcared "on the stack", meaning the last variable is first in memory:

```
buf: 00 00 00... 00; score: 00 00 00 00
```